# How to parse BSON date (unix epoch) using OPENJSON in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, json

I want to insert a JSON document (created by my python client with `json.dumps(payload, default=json_util.default))`) to my db. I have the following procedure in SQL Server (Azure).

```
CREATE PROCEDURE InsertReading(@reading nvarchar(max))
AS BEGIN
insert into Readings(IdMongo, Value, Name, Date)
SELECT _id, value, name, date
FROM OPENJSON (@reading)
WITH (_id nvarchar(50),
        value float,
        date datetime,
        name nvarchar(50))
END
```

It works fine when I execute it with data like this (not the document I have -  testing only):

```
EXEC InsertReading '{
"value" : 21.625,
"name" : "myname",
"date" : "2016-03-30T07:38:27.102Z"
}'
```

But it fails with

```
EXEC InsertReading '{"date": {"$date": 1503074335547}, "value": 23.5, "name": "myname"}'
```

Error (date conversion fails and returns null):

```
Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'Date', table 'db.dbo.Readings'; column does not allow nulls. INSERT fails.
```

How to insert that JSON correctly? Preferably without changing the date format in client (I'm sending it simultaneously to mongo and sql).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah, that's no fun. SQL Server has no support for this format, so you have to construct the date manually.

```
SELECT _id, [value], [name], 
    COALESCE(
        [date], 
        DATEADD(MILLISECOND, [dateMillis] % 1000, 
             DATEADD(SECOND, [dateMillis] / 1000, '19700101'))
    )
FROM OPENJSON (@reading)
WITH (_id nvarchar(50),
        [value] float,
        [date] datetime,
        [dateMillis] bigint '$.date."$date"',
        [name] nvarchar(50))
```

This will allow you to pass both formats (date/time literals and millisecond offsets).

Comment: This works fine. I only had to use `datetime2` instead of `datetime` to insert dates with higher precision, like `2017-08-19T15:42:46.5065156Z`